# How image included within the text in RichBox in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, richtextbox

When inside the tool I want to text included in the image between the place where I want to speak, as the following picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4uK4.jpg)

I tried the following code but the photo does not show the speech, but end of the sentence appears:

```
Dim para As New Paragraph()
Dim bitmap As New BitmapImage(New Uri("D:\Happy.png"))
Dim image As New Image()
image.Source = bitmap
image.Width = 20
para.Inlines.Add(image)
RTB.Document.Blocks.Add(para)
```

Answer (score 0):

See this link for examples [Inline Images or Other Elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681613(v=vs.95).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-8).

```
'A RichTextBox with an image.
Private Sub ImageRTB()
    'Create a new RichTextBox.
    Dim MyRTB As New RichTextBox()

    ' Create a Run of plain text and image.
    Dim myRun As New Run()
    myRun.Text = "Displaying text with inline image"
    Dim MyImage As New Image()
    MyImage.Source = New BitmapImage(New Uri("flower.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
    MyImage.Height = 50
    MyImage.Width = 50
    Dim MyUI As New InlineUIContainer()
    MyUI.Child = MyImage

    ' Create a paragraph and add the paragraph to the RichTextBox.
    Dim myParagraph As New Paragraph()
    MyRTB.Blocks.Add(myParagraph)

    ' Add the Run and image to it.
    myParagraph.Inlines.Add(myRun)
    myParagraph.Inlines.Add(MyUI)

    'Add the RichTextBox to the StackPanel.
    MySP.Children.Add(MyRTB)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, but this is not what I want.
Tool I have found in the window and the texts and I want to insert the image within the pre-existing texts, I do not want the creation of a new tool through the code and put the texts.

Answer (score 0):

The solution found and this is the code:

```
Dim tp As TextPointer = rtb.CaretPosition.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward)
Dim bm As New BitmapImage()
bm.BeginInit()
bm.UriSource = New Uri("Happy.png", UriKind.Relative)
bm.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad
bm.EndInit()
Dim img As New Image()
img.Source = bm
img.Width = 20
img.Height = 20
img.Stretch = Stretch.Fill
Dim container As New InlineUIContainer(img, tp)
```

thank you :)